# SyntaxRewriter and multiple statements

Tags: roslyn

I've encountered a tricky situation using the SyntaxRewriter in Roslyn.  I'd like to rewrite certain kinds of statements, including local variable declarations.  The solution requires me to transform the statements in question into multiple statements, as in the following trivial example:

```cs
void method()
{
    int i;
}
```

becomes

```cs
void method()
{
    int i;
    Console.WriteLine("I declared a variable.");
}
```

I've seen other examples where blocks are used to accomplish something similar, but of course in the case of a variable declaration, the scope of the declaration will be affected.  I came up with the following solution, but I'm balking at it.  It seems over-complicated, and requires a break in the visitor pattern:

```cs
class Rewriter: SyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxList<TNode> VisitList<TNode>(SyntaxList<TNode> list)
    {
        if (typeof(TNode) == typeof(StatementSyntax))
            return Syntax.List<TNode>(list.SelectMany(st => RewriteStatementInList(st as StatementSyntax).Cast<TNode>()));
        else
            return base.VisitList<TNode>(list);
    }

    private IEnumerable<SyntaxNode> RewriteStatementInList(StatementSyntax node)
    {
        if (node is LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax)
            return PerformRewrite((LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax)node);
        //else if other cases (non-visitor) 

        return Visit(node).AsSingleEnumerableOf();
    }

    private IEnumerable<SyntaxNode> PerformRewrite(LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax orig)
    {
        yield return orig;
        yield return Syntax.ParseStatement("Console.WriteLine(\"I declared a variable.\");");
    }
}
```

What am I missing?  Editing statements and removing them (via empty statement) seem more straight forward than rewriting to multiples.

My take on the answer:

```cs
class Rewriter : SyntaxRewriter
{
    readonly ListVisitor _visitor = new ListVisitor();

    public override SyntaxList<TNode> VisitList<TNode>(SyntaxList<TNode> list)
    {
        var result = Syntax.List(list.SelectMany(_visitor.Visit).Cast<TNode>());
        return base.VisitList(result);
    }

    private class ListVisitor : SyntaxVisitor<IEnumerable<SyntaxNode>>
    {
        protected override IEnumerable<SyntaxNode> DefaultVisit(SyntaxNode node)
        {
            yield return node;
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<SyntaxNode> VisitLocalDeclarationStatement(
             LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax node)
        {
            yield return node;
            yield return Syntax.ParseStatement("Console.WriteLine(\"I declared a variable.\");");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is a simple way to make your `Rewriter` more visitor-like: use another visitor to process the nodes in the list:

```cs
class Rewriter: SyntaxRewriter
{
    readonly Visitor m_visitor = new Visitor();

    public override SyntaxList<TNode> VisitList<TNode>(SyntaxList<TNode> list)
    {
        var result = Syntax.List(list.SelectMany(m_visitor.Visit).Cast<TNode>());
        return base.VisitList(result);
    }
}

class Visitor : SyntaxVisitor<IEnumerable<SyntaxNode>>
{
    protected override IEnumerable<SyntaxNode> DefaultVisit(SyntaxNode node)
    {
        return new[] { node };
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<SyntaxNode> VisitLocalDeclarationStatement(
         LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax node)
    {
        return new SyntaxNode[]
               {
                   node,
                   Syntax.ParseStatement(
                       "Console.WriteLine(\"I declared a variable.\");")
               };
    }
}
```

Note that this is not safe and will throw an `InvalidCastException` if you return a collection that contains object that is not `TNode` from the `Visitor`.

Comment: I was thinking of doing it this way.  The only down side would be that IEnumerable will only make sense inside a call to VisitList.  I think a builder/writer, would be a compelling answer, but I think I'm over obsessing about it :)  I'll upvote you guys later, apparently I don't have enough SO clout yet.

Comment: Why is it a problem that `IEnumerable` makes sense only in a call to `VisitList()`? Whenever it makes sense to replace one node with a sequence of nodes, that node should be a part of some list, I think.

Comment: Actually, I didn't notice you were only calling `Visitor` directly and only from `VisitList`.  I like this solution a lot.  I'm going to put it in my question, with `yield return` to generate the iterators and nest the list visitor class.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a radically better way to handle this.  One other approach that is slightly more "visitor like" is to use `VisitLocalDeclaration` to annotate nodes that you want to replace with something like: `return (base.Visit(node).WithAdditionalAnnoations(myAnnotation);`.  Then in VisitList, you can just find the child nodes that your annotation and do the rewrite at that point.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin.  That's something I didn't look at for this.  So if I were to take that approach, I would still need to case out any special handling per node type, when rewriting in VisitList, correct?

Answer (score 2):

I was browsing through the Roslyn source code to see how the Roslyn team themselves do this. Here's an example: http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features/R/bcd389b836bf7b4c.html

In a nutshell, I think it looks more or less like this. (this rewriter happens to just delete StatementExpressions, but you can see it's built out of an iterator method, so it's easy to add methods too).

```cs
class TreeRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxNode VisitBlock(BlockSyntax node)
        => node.WithStatements(VisitList(SyntaxFactory.List(ReplaceStatements(node.Statements))));

    public override SyntaxNode VisitSwitchSection(SwitchSectionSyntax node)
        => node.WithStatements(VisitList(SyntaxFactory.List(ReplaceStatements(node.Statements))));

    IEnumerable<StatementSyntax> ReplaceStatements(IEnumerable<StatementSyntax> statements)
    {
        foreach (var statement in statements)
        {
            if (statement is ExpressionStatementSyntax) continue;
            yield return statement;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I drive that code:

```cs
var rewriter = new TreeRewriter();
var syntaxTree = await document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync();
var root = await syntaxTree.GetRootAsync();
var newRoot = rewriter.Visit(root);
var newDocument = document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
```