# Rewrite SyntaxNode to two SyntaxNodes

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm using Roslyn's [`CSharpSyntaxRewriter`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/CSharpSyntaxRewriter.cs,72741c962906b744) to rewrite the following:

```
string myString = "Hello ";
myString += "World!";
```

to:

```
string myString = "Hello ";
myString += "World!"; Log("myString", myString);
```

My syntax rewriter overrides `VisitAssignmentExpression` as follows.

```
public override SyntaxNode VisitAssignmentExpression(AssignmentExpressionSyntax node)
{
    //Construct a new node without trailing trivia
    var newNode = node.WithoutTrailingTrivia();
    InvocationExpressionSyntax invocation = //Build proper invocation

    //Now what? I need to bundle up newNode and invocation and return them
    //as an expression syntax
}
```

I have been able to "cheat" this limitation when dealing with `StatementSyntax` by constructing a `BlockSyntax` with missing braces:

```
var statements = new SyntaxList<StatementSyntax>();
//Tried bundling newNode and invocation together
statements.Add(SyntaxFactory.ExpressionStatement(newNode));
statements.Add(SyntaxFactory.ExpressionStatement(invocation));
var wrapper = SyntaxFactory.Block(statements);

//Now we can remove the { and } braces
wrapper = wrapper.WithOpenBraceToken(SyntaxFactory.MissingToken(SyntaxKind.OpenBraceToken))
    .WithCloseBraceToken(SyntaxFactory.MissingToken(SyntaxKind.CloseBraceToken)
```

However this approach won't work with `AssignmentExpressionSyntax` as `BlockSyntax` cannot be cast to `ExpressionSyntax`. ([The CSharpSyntaxRewriter tries to make this cast.](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/obj/Debug/Syntax.xml.Generated.cs,660bc9ee4d6b8d3e))

How can I rewrite one SyntaxNode into two SyntaxNodes?

Have I run up against a limitation of the API, or are there any tricks similar to the above that someone could share?

Comment: Adding a comment, because it stumped me. `SyntaxList<StatementSyntax>` is immutable, so you have to assign each time, i.e. `statements = statements.Add(SyntaxFactory.ExpressionStatement(newNode));`

Comment: There is a good discussion here, with a bunch of options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775335/syntaxrewriter-and-multiple-statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to visit the parent `ExpressionStatementSyntax` and replace that with a `BlockSyntax`.

You cannot insert a `BlockSyntax` as an expression in an expression statement.